# How to test if file upload is supported on server using php

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my code to test for MySQL:

```
if (extension_loaded('mysqlnd')) {
   echo "mysql supported";
} else {
   echo "mysql not supported";
};
```

How can I check to see if uploads are allowed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if(ini_get('file_uploads') == 1)
{
  echo 'HTTP Upload Enabled';
}
else
{
  echo 'HTTP Upload Disabled';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the [`file_uploads`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) INI setting:

> Whether or not to allow HTTP file uploads. See also the `upload_max_filesize`, `upload_tmp_dir`, and `post_max_size` directives.

If you test that using [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/ini_get), you should be able to detect whether file uploads are enabled. (Make sure you test this, though.)

Theoretically, setting `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` to a very low value could effectively block uploads as well. Also, file uploads could also be blocked on web server level. That will be impossible for you to detect without actually trying to do an upload.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there's such thing like disabling file uploads and checking file upload support. You only can check things like, max allowed size, etc, like:

```
$maxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Hope it helps