# error in uploading file into mysql database in php

Tags: php

I'm getting an error when i upload a file into mysql: "Error! A file was not sent!".

Here is my PHP code please look into it and let me know where the error is in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>MySQL file upload example</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="add_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
<p>
    <a href="list_files.php">See all files</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

add_file.php

```
<?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pwd', 'myTable');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']    ['tmp_name']));
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
        INSERT INTO `file` (
        `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
        )
        VALUES (
        '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
        )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
            . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
    echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
    . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
} else
{
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Comment: `Error! A file was not sent!` is in the `else{}` block of `if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {...}`. So it looks like you are not uploading/posting a file.

Comment: You have a space at `file_get_contents($_FILES ['uploaded `
Don't think that is causing your error though

Comment: how come im browsing the file and clicking upload.

Comment: Maybe your file will not upload because it is too big. Your server will have setting to restrict the maximum filesize that can be uploaded. Have you tried uploading a very small text file?

Comment: no not the space i just tried it just now

Comment: yes i did tried small file but its the same error

Comment: you could try printing your `$_FILES` array, to make sure your name/key is correct - put `print_r($_FILES);` at the top of your page before your `if(isset(...`

Comment: i did and got this Array ( ) Error! A file was not sent!

Comment: Is it possible that file upload is not allowed on your server? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8654516/689579 about seeing if `ini_get('file_uploads')` is enabled - `if(ini_get('file_uploads') == 1){echo 'HTTP Upload Enabled';} else { echo 'HTTP Upload Disabled'; }` http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

Comment: HTTP Upload Disabled, how to enable it ?

Comment: i just enable file upload but same error.

Comment: Do you still get `HTTP Upload Disabled` after enabling `file_uploads`?

Comment: no its enable. i check it

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one non-file form field to have the form submit properly. The $_FILES array does not get set without data in the $_POST array. Adding a hidden form field above your file input field will fix it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_field">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
```

Or add a name attribute to the submit button input tag like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file">
```

- I have a working demo here: http://lytsp33d.com/testing/
- and a nonworking demo here: http://lytsp33d.com/testing2/

In the non working demo you'll see that, even though the file is uploaded the $_FILES array is empty.

Comment: no its not working for me. i did the change and add <input type="text" name="text_field"> above me code but its showing tow input txt.

Comment: where is your post, im not finding it.

Comment: but when i add this <input type="text" name="text_field"><br> it show tow input text boxs any idea why it shouldn't  right

Comment: im not finding ur ini config

Comment: i tried another script same problem array is empty. what do you think is the problem...!!!:(

Comment: I'm not sure. Can anyone else verify that this solution works though? I would like to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you get `HTTP Upload Disabled` when doing

```
if(ini_get('file_uploads') == 1){
   echo 'HTTP Upload Enabled';
} 
else { 
   echo 'HTTP Upload Disabled';
}
```

`file_uploads` on your server is turned off by default

If you have access to / and can modify your `php.ini` file -

```
file_uploads = 1
```

In your `.htaccess` file -

```
php_value  file_uploads  1
```

Or at the top your php page

```
<?php
  ini_set('file_uploads',1);
?>
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads